# How to split train/test in recommender systems

Tags: machine-learning, dataset, recommender-system

I am working with the MovieLens10M dataset, predicting user ratings.  If I want to fairly evaluate my algorithm, how should I split my training v. test data?

By default, I believe the data is split into train v. test sets where 'test' contains movies previously unseen in the training set.  If my model requires each movie to have been seen at least once in the training set, how should I split my data?  Should I take all but N of each user's ratings for all the data and evaluate my performance on the held out NxUser_num  ratings?

Comment: in industry, it's preferred splitting by time, so that to predict the future.

Answer (score 5):

[`Leave-one-out`](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/%7Eschneide/tut5/node42.html) cross validation is probably the most straight-forward way to address this.  If you happen to be using a model that requires a lot of time to train, then leave n% out might be more appropriate.

The method involves eliminating one known rating and trying to predict it.  If you want to remove n percent of the ratings, just choose them randomly rather than choosing a specific number of every user's ratings.  And keep n pretty small - on the order of 10% or less.

Here is a good treatment of cross validation methods for recommender systems, [An Evaluation Methodology for Collaborative Recommender Systems](https://chrome.deib.polimi.it/images/8/8e/Cremonesi_2008_CROSSMEDIA.pdf).  Generally:

> Holdout is a method that splits a dataset into two parts: a training
> set and a test set. These sets could have different proportions. In
> the setting of recommender systems the partitioning is performed by
> randomly selecting some ratings from all (or some of) the users. The
> selected ratings constitute the test set, while the remaining ones are
> the training set. This method is also called leave-k-out. In [17],
> Sarwar et al. split the dataset into 80% training and 20% test data.
> In [18] several ratios among training and test (from 0.2 to 0.95 with
> an increment of
> 0.05) are chosen and for each one the experiment is repeated ten times with different training and test sets and finally the results are
> averaged. In [13] the test set is made by 10% of users: 5 ratings for
> each user in the test set are withheld.
>
> Leave-one-out is a method
> obtained by setting k = 1 in the leave-k-out method. Given an active
> user, we withhold in turn one rated item. The learning algorithm is
> trained on the remaining data. The withheld element is used to
> evaluate the correctness of the prediction and the results of all
> evaluations are averaged in order to compute the final quality
> estimate. This method has some disadvantages, such as the overfitting
> and the high computational complexity. This technique is suitable to
> evaluate the recommending quality of the model for users who are
> already registered as members of the system. Karypis et al. [10]
> adopted a trivial version of the leave-one-out creating the test set
> by randomly selecting one of the non-zero entries for each user and
> the remaining entries for training. In [7], Breese et al. split the
> URM in training and test set and then, in the test set, withhold a
> single randomly selected rating for each user.
>
> A simple variant of the
> holdout method is the m-fold cross-validation. It consists in dividing
> the dataset into m independent folds (so that folds do not overlap).
> In turn, each fold is used exactly once as test set and the remaining
> folds are used for training the model. According to [20] and [11], the
> suggested number of folds is 10. This technique is suitable to
> evaluate the recommending capability of the model when new users
> (i.e., users do not already belong to the model) join the system. By
> choosing a reasonable number of folds we can compute mean, variance
> and confidence interval.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You could, but you'd introduce 'data leakage'. To illustrate this, let's assume you have the dates these ratings were made, and they go all the way to 2022.

Your test set would contain each user's last n ratings, and some of those ratings would be from 2021, 2020 and further in past, because not every user has rated something recently. So John might have made all last rating in 2021, and that goes into the test set. However, many users will have made multiple ratings in 2022, and most of these will be in the training set. So now you're training a model on data up to 2022, but testing on some data from before 2022. Your model essentially knows the future! As a result it might perform better than it would when deployed and running on new ratings coming in.

A better option would be to train on everything before X months ago, and test on X months ago to the present. Assuming you have the time the ratings were made of course, which you likely would in a real scenario.