# Cross validation for Collaborative filter-based recommendation systems

Tags: machine-learning, dataset, cross-validation, recommender-system

I am an absolute beginner and am trying to implement collaborative filter for furniture ecommerce (think wayfair). I need some guidance about cross-validation strategy.

**Situation**:
I am working on a fictitious dataset relating to customers' furniture purchases. Let's assume that the customers buy furniture and related items at a time. "At a time" because they mostly buy them either when furniture breaks or when they need to be replaced because the needs have changed (kids have grown up etc.). Hence, a typical buying cycle is somewhere between 6 and 9 years. Moreover, by "related items" I mean that they would buy related items such as mattresses, bed sheets along with bed.

When the customer visits the furniture store website for the first time (defined as *"new customer"*), they indicate their preferences in terms of things they are looking for in the furniture: size, handling etc. This was done to avoid "*cold-start problem.*" in recommender system.

Here's how the dataset looks like:
[image: Table1]

My goal is to recommend products for each *new customer* who visits the website, which happens every 6 to 9 years because of buying cycle explained above. Predicting right products for the new customer will help reduce sales cycle and possibly improve customer satisfaction.

The question is **how should I split the dataset into test and validation?**

I read through https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40494952/splitting-in-recommender-system, [How to split train/test in recommender systems](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/6814/how-to-split-train-test-in-recommender-systems), and https://arxiv.org/pdf/2007.13237.pdf.

Reading above sources, I believe that realistically, I have three options and here are my thoughts for each:

**1) Separate recent *k* transactions for *each customer* for testing:**
This might suffer from *data leakage problem* i.e. for some customers I might have data from 2011 to 2020 in training set, but for others, I might have data from 2016 to 2019. I might already know that during Covid (2020), office desk was popular. So, I would automatically recommend this for users with training data until 2019. This will be considered cheating, I think.

**2) Holdout: Shuffle and then separate last k transactions for testing:**
Timing is important. So, this might not work because I might use a future transaction to predict something in the past, which wouldn't make any sense.

**3) Randomly shortlist k customers for testing, and then train using remaining customers:**
I am a big fan of this method because my goal is to predict product recommendations for new customers. I won't have cold-start problem because the customers would provide the preferences, and I will be able to use preferences from training customers to match (using collaborative filter) preferences of new customers. However, I am not too sure whether training customers' preferences will represent new customers.

Am I on the right track? I have spent a lot of time on this problem, and I would appreciate any guidance.

Comment: If your goal is to predict preferences of a totally new customer, you have no previous purchases, so I'm not sure the collaborative filtering component of your model would do anything? You're perhaps best going with a pure content recommender